# Как принимать оплату за услуги в AppStore

Tags: in-app-purchases, appstore

Всем привет!

Хочу сделать iOS приложение по аренде транспорта, но не понимаю как принимать оплату.
В свете последних событий нет возможности оплачивать услуги в приложении через Apple Pay. Но судя по таким приложениям, как аренда самокатов, каршеринга и д.р. оплата принимается через сторонние сервисы, хотя на сколько знаю это запрещено в эпл.

Подскажите, как такое можно реализовать в небольшом приложении по аренде велосипедов?

Главный вопрос в том, что бы такое приложение прошло ревью в апсторе

Answer (score 1):

Для России нашел ЮКасса или Тинькоф, у них есть для всех вариантов предложения, в т.ч. для маркетплейсов

Answer (score 0):

Запрещена продажа цифровых товаров через сторонние сервисы. Аренда это физический продукт, поэтому можно использовать не ApplePay